# WPFToolkit Charts leak memory, any fixes or alternatives?

Tags: wpf, wpftoolkit

I've found that the chart controls in the WPFToolkit library leak memory. I am using them in an MVVM setup, where I bind the ItemSource of the chart control (PieSeries or BarSeries) to an ObservableCollection on my ViewModel. I sometimes Clear() the ObservableCollection and then Add() new KeyValuePairs to it (when the user triggers a SelectionChanged event on a ComboBox to see a different set of data). That's how I change the data in the chart. However, the memory is not released. I've found that if I comment out the control in the XAML, the memory problem goes away, even if I still Add to the collection.

Are there any good fixes for this memory leak? Or alternative toolkits that are free?

Thanks!

Comment: In the meantime, I've decided to give amCharts a try.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a known issue, here is a quick fix:

```
<dvc:Chart.Palette>
    <dv:ResourceDictionaryCollection>
        <!-- Note: This a memory leak fix, do not remove-->
    </dv:ResourceDictionaryCollection>
</dvc:Chart.Palette>
```

Found here: http://wpf.codeplex.com/discussions/216609